# Weird edges after sub d

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I am trying to model a fish, I have a very simple model with quads only and a mirror and a sub d modifier, however when I turn on the sub d I get weird edges on top and bottom of the fish.

[image]

[image]

after sub d

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Mirror modifier make sure that "merge" and "clipping" is checked. Also make sure that there is no internal polygons running down the middle of the mesh.

Comment: it was internal polygons thank you so much